# DataGridView.SelectionChanged se dispara al agregar una fila

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un DataGridView y tres métodos:

- El método A agrega filas al DataGridView
- El método B, en base a cierto criterio, selecciona una de esas filas
- El método C, en respuesta al SelectionChanged, ejecuta un código tomando como referencia la fila seleccionada

Pero resulta que, al agregar una fila, el método A dispara el evento SelectionChaged, el cual a su vez dispara el método C, ocasionando un comportamiento indeseado.

¿Existe una manera de evitar que esto suceda?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Agregar una nueva fila provoca un cambio en la seleccion (se selecciona la nueva fila). Tal vez necesitas algun tipo de flag? Podrias hacer un [mcve] para que veamos que pasa?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar declarando una variable global que sirva de bandera:

La variable en un inicio se pone como verdadera, al ejecutar el método A la pasas a falso
y validas al inicio de tu evento, si es falso regresas.

Terminar de ejecutar Método A y vuelves a ponerla en verdadero para que ya se pueda
entrar el evento.

```
Public Class frm
    Dim _bEntra As Boolean = True

    Private Sub agregaFila()
        _bEntra = False
        datagrid.Rows.Add("fila")
        _bEntra = True
    End Sub

     Private Sub datagrid_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
        If Not _bEntra Then Return

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes quitar el evento al inicio de tu función y volverlo a añadir al final.

Me explico:

Por lo que entiendo el problema viene cuando, al ejecutar el código del método A, se produce el evento que desencadena el método C, luego lo que haríamos sería que cuando se llamara al método A, lo primero que se hiciera fuera desactivar el método C (Eliminar el handler que lo desencadena), tras esto ejecutaríamos el código correspondiente al método A sin miedo a que se lance el método C, y después volveríamos a asignar el evento desencadenante del método C. Es un poco lioso pero quedaría algo así (el código que pongo es inventado, ya que no has proporcionado ninguno):

```vb
Private Sub Metodo_A(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles evento.metodoA
  'desvinculamos el método de su desencadenante:
  RemoveHandler Evento.MetodoC, AddressOf Metodo_C
  'Código que quieras que se ejecute en el método A
  MessageBox.Show("Me ejecuto sin que se lance el método C")
  'Volvemos a vincular el método C a su desencadenante:
  AddHandler Evento.MetodoC, AddressOf Metodo_C
End Sub
```

Quizá hay una manera más óptima de solucionar tu problema, pero es lo que se me ocurre ahora.

Pruébalo y nos cuentas!